# Argc returning as 1, argv returning NULL, despite putting in command line arguments

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I suppose I'm a little rusty on C command line arguments. I looked at some old code of mine, but no matter what this version keeps segfaulting.

The way this would be ran is ./foo -n num (where num is the number the user inputs in the command line)

But somehow it isn't working. Where do I go wrong?

EDIT: It's segfaulting when I try to access atoi(optarg) which is atoi(0x0) which segfaults.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int maximum_n = max_n(); /* Stores the maximum value in the sequence a long can hold */
    unsigned long *array = NULL;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":n:")) != -1) {

        switch(c) {
        case 'n':
            if(atoi(optarg) > maximum_n) {
                printf("n is too large -- overflow will occur\n");
                printf("the largest Fibonacci term than can be calculated is %d\n", maximum_n); 
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else {
                array = fib_array(atoi(optarg));
            }
            break;
        }   
    }

    printf("The %d Fibonacci term is %lu\n", atoi(optarg), array[atoi(optarg)]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argv[0]` is your first argument, a usual shell sets it to the basename of the executable, btw.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that much. That's why I was saying that argv[1] is the issue here, as it's returning null but shouldn't be. It should be whatever the user entered.

Comment: Tyler, you have to understand that if argv[0] is set, argc is 1. If argv[1] is set, argc has to be at least 2.

Comment: I feel like you're kind of missing the point. Why is the code segfaulting? Where did I screw up in this? It's not that long, so I can't imagine it's that hard to see.

Comment: `getopt` knows about the arguments, so you don't have to.

Comment: When you start `./foo -n 10` you expect that argc is 2 and argv[1] is 10. Correct is, that argv[1] is '-n', argv[2] is '10' and argc is 3.

Comment: I posted the full code. Hopefully it will clear up whatever the issue is. optarg is coming back as 0x0, so when I try to do atoi(optarg) it's segfaulting.

Comment: I'm not an expert on getopt, but are you supposed to put a `:` with no preceding argument?

Comment: I tried removing that first : but it didn't seem to help. Still segfaulted in the same way.

Comment: A colon at the front changes the behavior when encountering an invalid option.

Comment: You probably mean: `array[atoi(optarg) - 1]`. As it stands if you ask for the nth element you're actually getting the (n+1)th element.

Comment: You are not accessing `argv` or `argc` directly anywhere. Why do you thing they are problematic? Where exactly does it segfault?

Comment: It's segfaulting when I try to access atoi(optarg) which is atoi(0x0) which segfaults.

Comment: See the update to my answer for why it's segfaulting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like many programming languages, in C `argv[0]` usually contains the name of the program. The value actually depends on the arguments to the `exec*` system call that was used to start the process. For your purposes, that part doesn't matter. What is important to note is that argc will always be one greater than the number of arguments your program received on the command line. In your case `argc == 3` and the value of `argv` should look like

```
argv[0]: "./foo"
argv[1]: "-n"
argv[2]: "10"
```

The reason your program is segfaulting is you're accessing `optarg` after it's no longer valid. The value of `optarg` can change every time you call `getopt()`. When you call it outside of the while loop, it has been changed to `NULL`. You should store the value of `atoi(optarg)` to a variable while you're in the switch case for `'n'`.

Since you're still confused about it, I've updated your code with the necessary fixes.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;
    int maximum_n = max_n(); /* Stores the maximum value in the sequence a long can hold */
    unsigned long *array = NULL;
    int n = -1;

    while((c = getopt(argc, argv, ":n:")) != -1) {

        switch(c) {
        case 'n':
            n = atoi(optarg);
            if(n > maximum_n) {
                printf("n is too large -- overflow will occur\n");
                printf("the largest Fibonacci term than can be calculated is %d\n", maximum_n); 
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            }
            else {
                array = fib_array(n);
            }
            break;
        }   
    }

    if (n == -1)
    {
        printf("You must specify a value with -n\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("The %d Fibonacci term is %lu\n", atoi(optarg), array[n]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, why exactly is my code segfaulting? argv[0] is fine (it's the name of my program) but argv[1] is 0x0 and argv[2] is gibberish.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the incomplete code you've posted, so it must be something about the code you're omitting or your environment it is run in.

Comment: Indeed, it is not a matter of "c", but of the system environment. argv[0] being the name of the executable is a matter of convention and it is important for a programmer (especially of security relevant software) to _not_ rely on this. When you start a program with `exec*` it is easy to set argv[0] to an arbitrary value (also to a NULL pointer)

Comment: @Ctx Not all langauges provide the name of the executable (or rather whatever is passed to exec*) in the standard argument list. That's why I specified this was the case in C. It's possible OP is used to a different programming environment.

Comment: @KurtStutsman It is not the case that the language "C" provides the name of the executable in the standard argument list. This is, what I tried to explain to you.

Comment: I posted the full code. Hopefully it will clear up whatever the issue is. optarg is coming back as 0x0, so when I try to do atoi(optarg) it's segfaulting.

Comment: @Ctx I know it is not C that provides it. I never said C was providing anything. I said "in C", i.e. when programming in C. And Yes I'm aware it's not required to be the anme of the program, but I was attempting to keep the explanation simple.

Comment: @Ctx I have updated the answer to make it clearer I hope.

Comment: Shouldn't getopt only get called once? I only have one argument (-n).

Comment: It's a while loop. The first time you'll get the processing for `'-n'`. You have to call it again to find out you're at the end (return `-1`).

Comment: Something else, isn't the int c variable I created holding the return of getopt? Just like you said to hold it?

Comment: No, `c` contains the return value of `getopt()`. You need the save the return value of `atoi(optarg)`.

Comment: Weird. I've never, ever done that before. This code for command lines was copied from another program that worked perfectly fine. So I need to store the value of atoi(optarg) before the switch statement?

Comment: I edited my post again with your code and the fix I was suggesting. I hope that helps.

Comment: It works now. I just stored the value before the switch statement. How weird. Didn't have to do that ever before.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
 printf("The %d Fibonacci term is %lu\n", atoi(optarg), array[atoi(optarg)]);
```

When getopt has no more arguments to process, `optarg` is set to NULL. The function `atoi` has no proper error checking leading to SIGSEGV.